# ParallelJs in TypeScript where input and output data are of different types

Tags: javascript, typescript, parallel-processing, web-worker

I am trying to use ParallelJs (https://parallel.js.org/) in TypeScript to run some heavy process in parallel.

The array that I want to process in parallel has the following type:

```
type ParallelData= {
  input: //input type,
  output?: //output type
}
```

and I use the .map to process each item in the array. any of the functions inside the .map and later .then don't get called and while debugging the program jumps right out of it without processing the parallel data.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var Parallel = require('paralleljs');

const getProcesses = (object: Object3D) => {
  const processes: ParallelData[] = [];
  // filling in the data...

  return processes;
};

const doSomething = (data: ParallelData) => {
  let res = doHeavyProcess(data.input);
  return{input: data.input, output: res};
}

export const mainProcess= (object: SomeType) => {
  const processes = getProcesses(object);
  
  let p = new Parallel(processes);

  p.map(doSomething).then((result: ParallelData[])  => {
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: The types aren't really relevant. This is a runtime question. Where doew the `Parallel` constructor come from?

Comment: The Parallel is the instance of ParallelJs library imported as  `var Parallel = require('paralleljs');` https://parallel.js.org/

Comment: Gotcha. It's usually a mistake not to return from an asynchronous operation. E.g. `return p.map(... `. Without seeing more, it's difficult to see why the program exits